# Bulk insert is not working in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, csv, bulkinsert

Bulk insert is not working when I try to read in the `.CSV` file data from the network path, it throws an error message saying

> Cannot bulk load because the file couldn't be opened Operating system error code 5 (Access is denied)

If I try to bulk insert the same file data from the local drive of the server where SQL Server is running, it works fine without any issue. I checked the access rights with the network path, I do have full access. I need help to resolve this issue.

Comment: `**I** do have full access` Does SQL Server account has access too?

Comment: For debugging purpose, make it accessible to everyone. @lad2025 could be (and probably is) right that user, which runs SQL Server instance doesn't have access to shared file.

Comment: @lad2025 can you please elaborate on SQL Server account access? where i can find this account details

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44524/bulk-insert-through-network#44684

Answer (score 0):

The data file name  must specify a valid path from the server on which SQL Server is running. 
If the data file is a remote file, specify the Universal Naming Convention (UNC) name. 
A UNC name has the form :

```
  \\Systemname\ShareName\Path\FileName.
```

For example,

```
\\SystemX\DiskZ\Sales\update.txt.
```

For more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017